# Linear discriminant analysis with $p\gg n$

Tags: machine-learning, classification, discriminant-analysis, underdetermined

I am studying Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA). According to the formula for LDA, we are supposed to get the inverse of within group covariance. However, if $p\gg n$ (i.e., the dimension is much larger than the number of samples), what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to regularize your estimate of the covariance matrix. See [Regularization parameter to generate inverse covariance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154616/regularization-parameter-to-generate-inverse-covariance-matrix).

Regularization uses assumed prior-information to turn the covariance inversion into a well-posed problem (this is also mentioned in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Practical_use))

In practice, you can use a shrinkage estimator of the covariance matrix, such that:

$$\Sigma \rightarrow (\lambda-1)\Sigma+\lambda I_m$$

Where $\lambda$ is a hyperparameter that must be set in advance (and possibly optimized).

Comment: Thank you! That is a good strategy to get the inverse of a matrix. But in LDA, do people also use this method to solve this problem?

Comment: @coolcat Yes, it's even mentioned in the article linked. There are other ways to achieve regularization though. I only presented an alternative.